# Embed Google Maps into a Mobile site

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm new to web development and I'm stuck on a problem. I'm creating a mobile webpage and I would like the functionality of Google Maps on the webpage.

So pretty much I'm asking, how do I get the Google maps to show like it does, on the mobile webpage, to show up on my webpage? I would like the same functionality as the regular google maps including location detection as well layers and search capability.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of where I should be looking. I'm using jquery mobile on the rest of the site. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/. Focus on the JavaScript API: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. The complete reference, including navigation controls, can be found here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.8/reference